# Macbook with thunderbolt 3 and disk drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, optical-drive

I thought I just saw someone with (what I believe to be) a thunderbolt 3 and a disc drive on their MacBook, and I thought there were no more disc drives that were built into MacBooks (that have thunderbolt 3 ports also). The computer did look like one of the thicker, somewhat older MacBooks. What did I possibly see?

Answer (score 1):

Could it have been a [Kensington Lock Slot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot)? I believe the pre-retina MacBook Pros and MacBooks with optical drives all had them.

[image: Side view of old PowerBook with Kensington Lock Slot]

(Image: Wikipedia User "Yetzt", CC-BY-SA-2.0-Germany)

Comment: Yea, that is kinda what it looked like. It was just that (or whatever it was if not that) and the optical drive. Thanks. I knew it couldn't be a thunderbolt 3